# Bootstrap container trouble

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site in development and I have an about section and some product boxes, the product boxes are in a septate container to the about us information. Id like product container to be level with the first container... Here is my code
Image:

[image]
index

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <!-- Meta charset 
    ===================================================================================-->
            <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Title  
    ===================================================================================-->
            <title>Cold Cure Windows</title>

    <!-- Meta Tags  
    ===================================================================================-->
            <meta name="author" content="Thomas Withers @ Ice7Media">
            <meta name="description" content="Social Media Wizzards that handle all of your social media markerting.">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

            <!-- CSS Stylesheets  
    ===================================================================================-->
            <link href = "css/bootstrap-styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <link href = "css/animate.css" rel= "stylesheet">
            <link href = "css/global-styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <link href = "css/page-styles/home.css" rel= "stylesheet">
            <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "img/bocFav.png">

    <!-- Custom Fonts 
    ===================================================================================-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Vollkorn:400,400italic,700,700italic|Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        </head>

    <body>

==================================================================================-->
        <section id="about-us" class="about-us">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
                        <h3>About Us</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="action-button callback">
                            request a <span>Brochure</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="action-button callback">
                            <br><span>Contact Us</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="menu col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                        <span>Windows</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Scripts
        ===================================================================================-->
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC22aNgIjcYzx5Oel1m0Jtcem-W4R895fQ">              </script>
            <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/fix-nav.js"></script>
            <script src="js/map.js"></script>
            <script>
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000 //changes the speed
            })
            </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

home

```
  /*=========================================================================================== B9B9B9 */
.about-us {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}

.row-2 {
    padding-top: 350px;
    padding-left: 11px;
}

.menu-product {
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #0095D5;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-link:hover {
    transform: scale(1.045);
}

.menu-link > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0095D5;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.set-2{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-right: -100px;
}

.set-3{
    padding-top: 450px;
    padding-right: -100px;
}
```

Here are all the main files that my website uses... I hope someone can help me resolve this issue as it is stopping my development at the moment

Any help is much appreciated 
Thanks
Tom

Comment: damn that code is a lot of reading material for a most probably really small problem... ;) can you minimize the html and css and provider a [minimum verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @giorgio edited for you!

Comment: It looks like you just need to try to understand how the Bootstrap grid system works.

Comment: If you want them to appear in the same row you have to place them in the same `.row ` , and the total `col-*` must be 12( or below );

Answer (score 0):

You didn't nest your containers correctly. If I look at the code of the About Us section and strip it a bit, then you're left with:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            CTA's
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
        image button
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see you've placed three containers, with each one row underneath eachother. And it's displaying exactly that. What you want is *one* container, with *one* row, holding *two* columns next to eachother, and the first column holding *multiple* rows. Can you follow? Look at this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <p>...</p>

            <!-- Move the CTA's to here -->
            CTA's
        </div>

        <!-- And place this column in the same row -->
        <!-- Be sure to get rid of the col-lg-offset-x class -->
        <div class="menu col-lg-6">
            image button
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need all to be in the same level, We don't need three containers. 
When you use the second container it goes down.
You can use the code as below :

```
       <section id="about-us" class="about-us">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
                        <h3>About Us</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="action-button callback">
                            request a <span>Brochure</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="action-button callback">
                               <br><span>Contact Us</span>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                            <span>Windows</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

This is how it get's done if you need the things on the second and third container on the right half side.
Regards
*Nabeel*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this modification.

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="action-button callback">
              request a <span>Brochure</span>
            </div>

            <div class="action-button callback">
              <br><span>Contact Us</span>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```